# In Word 2010 or 2013, is it possible to create a reference to a specific source in the bibliography?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, bibliography

In answering [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/851717/auto-hot-linking-in-text-citations-to-a-bibliographic-entry/852868#852868) about automatically hot-linking from an in-text citation to its source in the bibliography, I discovered that bookmarks within a bibliography are deleted when the field is updated. (This makes sense, since it's all one field, but for the specific purpose, it's annoying.)

Is there a way to create a reference or pointer to an individual bibliography source that persists even after fields are updated?